# Counting primitive operations on recursive functions

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I'm reading *Algorithm Design and Applications*, by Michael T. Goodrich and Roberto Tamassia, published by Wiley. They teach the concept of primitive operations and how to count then in a given algorithm. Everything was clear to me until the moment they showed a recursive function (a simple recursive way to calculate the maximum value of an array) and its primitive operation count.

The function (in pseudo-code) is this:

```
Algorithm recursiveMax(A, n):
    Input: An array A storing n ≥ 1 integers.
    Output: The maximum element in A.
    
    if n = 1 then
        return A[0]
    return max{recursiveMax(A, n − 1), A[n − 1]}
```

where `A` is an array and `n` its length. The author states what follows concerning how we calculate the number of primitive operations this function has:

> As with this example, recursive algorithms are often quite elegant. Analyzing
> the running time of a recursive algorithm takes a bit of additional work, however.
> In particular, to analyze such a running time, we use a recurrence equation, which
> deﬁnes mathematical statements that the running time of a recursive algorithm must
> satisfy. We introduce a function T (n) that denotes the running time of the algorithm
> on an input of size n, and we write equations that T (n) must satisfy. For example,
> we can characterize the running time, T (n), of the recursiveMax algorithm as T(n) = 3 if n = 1 or T(n - 1) + 7 otherwise, assuming that we count each comparison, array reference, recursive call, max calculation, or return as a single primitive operation. Ideally, we would like to characterize a recurrence equation like that above in closed form, where no references to the function T appear on the righthand side. For the recursiveMax algorithm, it isn’t too hard to see that a closed form would be T (n) = 7(n − 1) + 3 = 7n − 4.

I can clearly understand that in the case of a single item array, our T(n) would be just 3 (only 3 primitive operations will occur, i.e. the comparision n = 1, the array index A[0] and the return operation), but I cannot understand why in the case where n is not 1 we have T(n-1) + 7. Why + 7? From where did we get this constant?

Also, I cannot comprehend this *closed form*: how did he get that T(n) = 7(n - 1) + 3?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You say you don't understand +7, but what do _you_ get when you count "each comparison, array reference, recursive call, max calculation, or return" in the case where n is not 1?

Comment: You can prove T(n) = T(n-1) + 7, T(1) = 3 has the solution T(n)=7(n-1)+3 by induction, or you can telescope the equations, or just try a few small n to convince yourself. Any introductory text on recurrence relations should be able to help you, and now is a good time to learn how to solve recurrence relations, because as you get to more advanced programs, the recurrence relations become a lot harder to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 Algorithm recursiveMax(A, n):
2 Input: An array A storing n ≥ 1 integers.
3 Output: The maximum element in A.
4     
5 if n = 1 then
6    return A[0]
7    return max{recursiveMax(A, n − 1), A[n − 1]}
```

T(n) = T(n-1)+7 holds because:

```
line 5: comparison n=1 => +1
line 7: return ==> +1
line 7: max ==> +1
line 7: computing n-1 for the argument of recursiveMax => +1
line 7: calling recursiveMax ==> +1
line 7: computing n-1 in A[n-1] ==> +1
line 7: array reference in A[n-1] ==> +1
```